# What is causing "cannot resolve symbol GradleException" in a Flutter project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I have created a Flutter project in Android Studio. The project was working fine until I opened the app-level [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) file as when I open is starts showing two errors: 1) 'Cannot resolve symbol Properties' and 2) 'cannot resolve symbol GradleException'

I click on "Open for editing in Android studio" and the error 1) disappeared, but 'cannot resolve symbol GradleException' is still there. I have the latest Gradle and Android Studio. The project was working fine until I opened this app-level Gradle file.

[image: As shown]

Answer (score 75):

Set *Project SDK* to *Android API Platform version 29* (or the latest version, 30), like so:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

And update `GradleException()` to `FileNotFoundException()`.

Please follow this: *[Have a problem on Cannot resolve symbol for properties and Gradle exception #29608](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608#issuecomment-548649907)*

This works for me.

Comment: @ib. please add the reason for editing, without it the discussion above is confusing.

Comment: changing android/app/build.gradle GradleException to FileNotFoundException solves for me.

Answer (score 52):

Use:

```
throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

I tried by removing the "new" keyword and it somehow worked for me.

I changed

```
throw new GradleException
```

to

```
throw GradleException.
```

Comment: running the project doesn't work after this change anymore

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS: Your app won't build!

Comment: anyone who knows about exception handling, knows that "throws new Exception()" creates a new instance of Exception class and throws that instance, when using "throw Exception()" There is no instance to throw and compiler will COMPLAIN!. (invalid syntax). One can use "throw" without "new" only when re-throwing an existing exception "throw exceptionInstance"

So this solution, shouldn't work. Not sure about groovy exception handling though which gradle uses.

Comment: Had to vote this down, outdated possibly? This fixed it for me: open build.gradle and replace GradleException with FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 10):

1. Open build.gradle file and set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 29
2. Click on File => Project Structure => Project then set Project SDK to Android API 29 platform
3. In project structure => Module and select dependencies in the right column and then set Module SDK to Android API 29 platform
4. Now open build.gradle and replace `GradleException` with `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Yes, worked for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like an IDE issue. Restart Android Studio, but going to menu *File* → *Invalidate Caches / Restart*. This happens to me when I synchronise Gradle after updates sometimes

Comment: Thanks this helped me when i was facing the "GradleException"-issue when modifying the gradle files to include Google Firebase in my Flutter project.

Comment: worked for me while modifying the same thing @JochenMarsaille, but I got a "FileNotFoundException"

Answer (score 0):

Removing the build folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the IDE can attack itself. To do this, change the folder named android (in the project location path) to OLDandroid.

Then, re-set your project as an android project via the IDE. (For VS Code: there is the phrase "set as android project" right under the emulator selection menu).

The IDE will create a new android folder for you at this stage. You can then move the necessary code blocks from the OLDandroid folder into the new android folder (manifests.xml, res, build properties, release keys etc.) and run the project.

If you are done with the OLDandroid folder, you can delete it.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the 'new' keyword, and everything is worked. Don't forget to keep your IDE up-to-date all the time.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You need to upgrade your SDK's version to the latest ones in your *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* at the app level.