# Flutter on Android Studio Errors

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I create new Flutter project in Android Studio it starts with errors !!

```
4 General Errors ,
Annotator 4 errors

build gradle 2 errors : "cannot resolve symbol 'properties'" and  "cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'"
-------------------------------------------------
settings.gradle 2 errors : "cannot resolve symbol 'File'" and "cannot resolve symbol 'properties'"

... more
```

Comment: Can you include your Gradle ?

Comment: what do you mean by that ? h ave some gradles , "build.gradle" , "gradle folder" or .... 
please guide me how to give you what you want

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59001977/10157127) might solve your issue